# Number of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How many irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Z_p$ of the form $x^2+ax+b$ are there?

No idea.

Comment: An irreducible polynomial of degree 2 must have no roots, and vice versa.

Comment: Hint: First count the reducible ones. Or use the search engine, this was asked (for arbitrary degree) at least 10 times on math.SE.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: if you were aware of that, why didn't you vote to close this question as duplicate? The arbitrary degree answer might be a little too complicated (what with Mobius function and all...), but the one I marked is a simple enough generalization.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is
$$
\frac{p^2 - p}{2}.
$$
The reason is that the polynomial
$$
x^{p^{2}} - x
$$
factors as the product of all the distinct irreducible, monic polynomials of degree dividing $2$, thus of degree $1$ or $2$, And there are $p$ monic polynomials of degree $1$.

More generally,
$$
x^{p^{d}} - x
$$
factors as the product of all the distinct irreducible, monic polynomials of degree dividing $d$. In general, to recover the number of the irreducible, monic polynomials of degree $d$, you have to use [Moebius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Number_of_monic_irreducible_polynomials_of_a_given_degree_over_a_finite_field).